# Modifiers Popup - Blender 2.9

Tags: modifiers

On previous versions of blender, I used this code to make a popup that shows all the modifiers.

```
class SFC_OT_modifiers_popup(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sfc.modifiers_popup"
    bl_label = "Modifiers Popup"
    # bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None 

    def check(self, context):
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        layout = self.layout
        
        ob = context.object
        md_self = bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers
        for md in ob.modifiers:
            box = layout.template_modifiers(md)
            if box:
                getattr(md_self, md.type)(md_self, box, ob, md) 

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        dpi_value = bpy.context.preferences.view.ui_scale
        coef = dpi_value * (-175) + 525
        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self, width=dpi_value * coef)
```

On Blender 2.9, they changed the code from

```
layout.template_modifier()
```

to

```
layout.template_modifiers()
```

Do you have an idea of how to make it work? We cannot add parameters to it anymore.

Previous >> https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.7/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout%20template_modifier#bpy.types.UILayout.template_modifier

New >> https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout%20template_modifier#bpy.types.UILayout.UILayout.template_modifiers

Thank you for your help ;)